# Unable to connect to mayan edms using docker in digital ocean server

Tags: python, docker, server, digital-ocean, mayanedms

1. I had set up my digital ocean server & docker successfully using ssh
2. Installed mayan using docker
3. Executed docker-compose and mayan was running normally in docker when I checked using docker ps command as follow:

[image]

Strangely when I accessed to my ip address I've got "this site can't be reached" messsage. When I tried using curl I've got "empty server response" message.

I did docker logs and I didn't find any error from the log as well. In my local computer everything works fine but when the exactly same code is cloned into digital ocean server I got this problem. I suspect there's something between docker, digital ocean server & port setting for docker. Any help is greatly welcome how to be able to connect to mayan edms over my digital ocean server ip address. Thanks

Comment: Silly question: have you checked the firewall settings on the VPS? Maybe that port is simply closed

Comment: I don't think it's closed because when I try to use another app with django & docker using port 80, it's working